# What are the often misunderstood concepts in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-2.0

Silverlight 2.0 has been out for a little while now.  What are the concepts that you often see used incorrectly or think are misunderstood?

Comment: I've seen people try to use it on web pages...

Comment: @Shog9, really, wouldn't trying to use Silverlight for anything other than a media player reveal a misundenrsanding?

Comment: Big one: Silverlight = MS x Flash

Comment: You could have used that as an answer, annakata.  Although if you do, I'd prefer a little more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its early days yet to have established a large enough set of instances of "usage" to determine those concepts which can be said to be "often" misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is data binding to controls. I find difficult to understand.

**[edit]**
I'm web developer, I have developed many web application. Data binding is very straight forward in asp.net. In Silverlight data binding is quite complected.
Web services used for data binding are in other project than Silverlight project, it create many problems during development 
Another thing I don't like abt Silverlight is that we have to create a seperate project for silverlight control. I want to create Silverlight page/control just like creating another web control.

Comment: This is not an answer, it looks more like a comment on a previous answer, by tucod.

Comment: This is a relevant answer. He is saying that binding is an example of an often misunderstood feature. The proof being that he himself finds it difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the var keyword only for LINQ queries. The type returned can vary, hence the use of type var.

Comment: This is not an answer, it looks more like a comment on a previous answer, by tucod.

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I don't understand the use of **var** keyword, or why should we use it instead of the real type identifier.

*Example:*

```
var t = new TextBox();
```

instead of

```
TextBox t = new TextBox();
```

Comment: Those both compile to the same thing. It tells the compiler to resolve the type at compile time. It is also required for anonymous types since they do not have a static type until compile time. I personally avoid it outside of simple uses (such as your example).

Comment: This is just a new feature of C# 3.0 rather than silverlight, you don't have to use it, it's intention is to reduce the code to a more readable size for complex types

Comment: This was implemented as a foundation feature of LINQ, but you do not have to use it.

Comment: Use it for when there IS NO 'real type identifier' - as with the results from a LINQ expression that returns a result set that is a composition of values from a number of sources. An anonymous type will be inferred and returned and var allows a type to be declared to receive it.

Comment: Saying `Textbox t = new TextBox()` violates DRY, i.e., it makes you repeat yourself. The same information is contained twice in the same line. That's bad coding style. IMO, you should default to using var unless you specifically need to distinguish the variable type from the return type. Type inference is a powerful feature, and we should use it as much as possible.